# How do I add a conditional to this statement to not echo empty $weekday

Tags: php, foreach, conditional-statements

I'm modifying a wordpress widget that is used to output a weekly class schedule in a list format.  As this code is now, it will output each weekday and then the class information for that day.  The problem is that even if there is a day with no classes, it still echoes that day name.  I want to skip echoing any $weekday that does not contain data within it's array.  Here is the code as is:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Output view template.
 *
 * Available Variables:
 * - $weekday_names: Array of weekday names to be used in table output.
 * - $weekdays: Array of used weekdays based on user preference.
 * - $start_hours: Array of unique start hours.
 * - $classes: Multi-dimensional array in the structure of $classes[weekday][start_hour].
 */
?>

<div id="wcs-schedule-list"> 
    <?php foreach ( $weekdays as $weekday ): ?>
    <h3><?php echo $weekday; ?></h3>
    <div class="list-container">
        <ul class="wcs-schedule-list">
        <?php foreach ( $start_hours as $start_hour ): ?>
        <?php echo WcsSchedule::model()->renderListItem( $classes, $start_hour, $weekday ) ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a `var_dump($start_hours);` of an empty $weekday.

```
Tuesday

array(6) { [1]=> string(8) "12:00 pm" [6]=> string(7) "2:00 pm" [4]=> string(7) "3:30 pm" [5]=> string(7) "6:00 pm" [2]=> string(7) "7:00 pm" [0]=> string(7) "8:15 pm" } array(6) { [1]=> string(8) "12:00 pm" [6]=> string(7) "2:00 pm" [4]=> string(7) "3:30 pm" [5]=> string(7) "6:00 pm" [2]=> string(7) "7:00 pm" [0]=> string(7) "8:15 pm" } array(6) { [1]=> string(8) "12:00 pm" [6]=> string(7) "2:00 pm" [4]=> string(7) "3:30 pm" [5]=> string(7) "6:00 pm" [2]=> string(7) "7:00 pm" [0]=> string(7) "8:15 pm" } array(6) { [1]=> string(8) "12:00 pm" [6]=> string(7) "2:00 pm" [4]=> string(7) "3:30 pm" [5]=> string(7) "6:00 pm" [2]=> string(7) "7:00 pm" [0]=> string(7) "8:15 pm" } array(6) { [1]=> string(8) "12:00 pm" [6]=> string(7) "2:00 pm" [4]=> string(7) "3:30 pm" [5]=> string(7) "6:00 pm" [2]=> string(7) "7:00 pm" [0]=> string(7) "8:15 pm" } array(6) { [1]=> string(8) "12:00 pm" [6]=> string(7) "2:00 pm" [4]=> string(7) "3:30 pm" [5]=> string(7) "6:00 pm" [2]=> string(7) "7:00 pm" [0]=> string(7) "8:15 pm" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other two answers are wrong. They still output the day, even if it's empty. Here you go:

```
<div id="wcs-schedule-list"> 
    <?php foreach ( $weekdays as $weekday ): ?>
    <?php if (empty($classes[$weekday])) continue; ?>
    <h3><?php echo $weekday; ?></h3>
    <div class="list-container">
        <ul class="wcs-schedule-list">
        <?php foreach ( $start_hours as $start_hour ): ?>
        <?php echo WcsSchedule::model()->renderListItem( $classes, $start_hour, $weekday ) ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

This answer assumes that `$classes[$weekday]` is empty when nothing is scheduled on the given `$weekday`.

Comment: this may not be right either, $start_hours will most likely never be empty

Comment: Yeah, this also isn't working.  $weekday would be an array, right?  So isn't there a way to see if the array is empty and then not echo it if so?

Comment: @ElefantPhace as I said, I was assuming `$start_hours` is an empty array when there are no events scheduled. `empty(array())` returns true. However, if Wordpress doesn't even set `$start_hours`, you would substitute `!isset()` instead. It depends on how Wordpress handles such an event. We need more information.

Comment: Again, just like the question about what $weekdays contains, $start_hours is most likely an array of hours such as 8am - 4pm. This is not where the problem lies

Comment: @Joel can you provide the result of `var_dump($start_hours)` for the case of a weekday having nothing scheduled? Also, [empty() recognizes empty arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: @ElefantPhace ah, I understand what you're saying now. I'd like to see what the `var_dump` contains before attempting a solution, though.

Comment: we know what empty() does. that's not what this is about. $start_hours is never getting changed in that foreach loop so it will NOT change from weekday to weekday

Comment: I put the vardump in the edited question above for an empty $weekday.

Comment: @Joel thanks. I'm guessing the values of the array elements change when events are added, so that the event is just pinned to the end of the string or something. In such a case, you could step through each element and check to make sure the string's length is greater than 8 (the length of "12:00 pm", the longest non-event string possible). Does that make sense? I'll edit my answer for this new info.

Comment: @blakeo_x you've completely misunderstood the question. This is not about the start hours. It's about whether or not a given weekday has any classes scheduled or not

Comment: I'm a total newbie, so may be way off, but since I'm only dealing with a finite amount of data (seven days), what if we do something like the above loop but instead of echoing the output as we go, you go through the loop and then if there is data to be output, that array is added to a new array, and if not then it is not put in the array, and then you print the array with data? If only I knew how to do it...

Comment: @ElefantPhace and if a class has hours scheduled, what happens? For example, if a class is scheduled for 2:00 PM, will element 1 (index 6) be changed to "2:00 pm - go to class" or equivalent?

Comment: @Joel that's one way to do it. The problem is ElefantPhace and I are disagreeing over (it seems) how to tell if a day has something scheduled or not. :p

Comment: Well I'm glad to hear it is a little more complicated than I first thought.  If it is helpful at all, the full code for the plugin is freely available here for anyone: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/weekly-class-schedule/

Comment: @blakeo_x well whoever can figure out how to make the code do the needed thing will be the winner-lol ;-p

Comment: No Blake. That has nothing to do with it! That is all handled by WcsSchedule::model->renderListItem   please think about what you're saying

Comment: Joel, try it yourself first then ask for help. We're not just gong to do it for you if you're not even going to try

Comment: @ElefantPhace OK, I looked back at the code, and you appear to be right; `$start_hours` doesn't change to reflect scheduled classes. So what does? How do we tell when we need to "go to class"?

Comment: renderListItem does that! Are you only reading parts of the question and parts of the comments?

Comment: No, I'm reading the whole thing! I see renderListItem taking three values in, and I assume that renderListItem does not have access to any data beyond those. So how can renderListItem tell when something is scheduled from those, but we can't?!

Comment: @ElefantPhace try what??  Would you like me to post all the bad attempted code I've been trying over here?  I'm not trying to get you to spoonfeed me stuff, but when you start telling me I need to start creating new methods, then you have gone pretty far over my head-if I knew how to do that, I would not be here asking what (I thought) was a simple conditional question.

Comment: @Joel try my new code? I took a look at the sourcecode for the module and I think I got it now. Fingers crossed :p

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ( $weekdays as $weekday ): ?>
<h3><?php echo $weekday;
    if(isset($weekday) && !empty($weekday)) { 
 ?></h3>
<div class="list-container">
    <ul class="wcs-schedule-list">
    <?php foreach ( $start_hours as $start_hour ): ?>
    <?php echo WcsSchedule::model()->renderListItem( $classes, $start_hour, $weekday ) ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php } endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This still echos $weekday even if it's empty.  I need to not echo <h3><?php echo $weekday; if there are no contents.

Comment: @joel can you please paste value of weekday when there is no content var_dump($weekday)

Comment: $weekdays is simply an array of days, Monday through Friday. It contains no other information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<div id="wcs-schedule-list"> ';
foreach ( $weekdays as $weekday ){
//you need to add a check with WcsSchedule first, to see if this $weekday has any classes before you begin outputting anything
    echo "<h3>$weekday</h3>";
    echo '<div class="list-container">';
    foreach ( $start_hours as $start_hour ) {
        echo '<ul class="wcs-schedule-list">';
        echo WcsSchedule::model()->renderListItem( $classes, $start_hour, $weekday );
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

This is not complete, you'll need to tweak it as I'm unfamiliar with what your using but, you'll need to first check if there are in classes using your model, I suppose.

You'll need to either come up with a way to check if there are classes for that day and go from there, or as above, loop through your start_hours before you output anything. In that for loop check if anything is returned from your model and go from there.

Comment: lol, oops, yes i see. But do you get what i mean about checking first if that weekday has any classes before outputting?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that?  I'm a newbie, but I am happy to do it if you can tell me what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can't help you there, I've never used WordPress before or WcsSchedule. Read the documentation, surely there must be a function that returns whether a given day has any scheduled classes or not...

Comment: I first asked the developer and was told they don't have that functionality, but that it would be a "simple PHP tweak".

Comment: It;s possible you'll need to add this needed method to their source... I've been looking at it, and indeed there is no functionality for this. It should be simple enough to add, but maybe you should try and if you have problems ask again